# Akismet for comments only

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, spam, akismet

Akismet is sometimes too strict on WP Contact Form 7 forms. For comments it seems to work just fine.

Ideally I would like to selectively exclude certain WPCF7 forms, but I could manage quite well without Akismet for all WPCF7 forms.

Is there a way to filter Akismet calls, the WPCF7 Akismet-call or how WPCF7 handles the ham/spam respons? Or maybe some simple parameter I can add to additional settings for a WPCF7 form to skip Akismet validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to disable Akismet in Contact Form 7 by adding this code to a file in `wp-content/mu-plugins/`:

```
<?php

function disable_akismet_in_contact_form_7() {
    remove_filter( 'wpcf7_spam', 'wpcf7_akismet', 10 );
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'disable_akismet_in_contact_form_7' );
```

If you're interested in improving Akismet's performance for everyone else using Contact Form 7, mark the false positives as such and then email us at support@akismet.com so we can look into why Akismet is too aggressive on your forms. Mention this comment in your email so that I'm sure to see it.

Comment: Thank you! Will test it soon. I have marked the false positives each time. Will mail you some more details in a moment.